# What is stored in alpha after the following code executes?

Tags: java

```
int[] alpha = new int[5];
int j;

for (j = 0; j < 5; j++)
{
alpha[j] = 2 * j;

if (j % 2 == 1)
  alpha[j - 1] = alpha[j] + j;
}
```

How do I find what is stored on "alpha"? I just know how to execute this, which I receive using [System.out.println(alpha); ]

```
[I@46798249
[I@46798249
[I@46798249
[I@46798249
[I@46798249
```

Comment: use [`java.util.Arrays.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(int[])) to convert arrays to strings

Comment: This should have been Java's default toString() implementation for arrays from the beginning.  Seeing the reference is almost always not what developers expect.

Comment: Thank You user2860598 AND Vandale!!  Would you guys mind telling me the point to find "stored" numbers in an array does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get what is stored at location 1 in alpha

```
System.out.print(alpha[0]);
```

Location 2...

```
System.out.print(alpha[1]);
```

All of it

```
for ( int i = 0 ; i < alpha.length ; i ++ )
     System.out.print(alpha[i]);
```

Or alternatively for all of it (Cleaner code)

```
for (int contents: alpha) {
    System.out.print(contents);
}
```

Both above have there different uses.

But to just dump to the console what is in the array:

```
System.out.print(java.util.Arrays.toString(alpha));
```